# EntityStoreException: Unsupported property type id 9

Tags: java, xodus

Using Xodus version `1.3.124` and the database is throwing:

```
jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.EntityStoreException: Unsupported property type id 9
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.tables.PropertyTypes.getPropertyType(PropertyTypes.java:56)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.tables.PropertyTypes.entryToPropertyValue(PropertyTypes.java:86)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.PersistentEntityStoreImpl.getPropertyValue(PersistentEntityStoreImpl.java:843)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.PersistentEntityStoreImpl.getProperty(PersistentEntityStoreImpl.java:827)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.PersistentEntity.getProperty(PersistentEntity.java:114)
```

Despite the property being registered:

```
@Override
  public PersistentEntityStore getPersistentEntityStore(String xodusRoot, String dir, boolean isReadOnly) {

    if(persistentEntityStoreCache == null) {
      persistentEntityStoreCache = buildPersistentEntityStoreCache();
    }
    PersistentEntityStore entityStore = persistentEntityStoreCache.get(xodusRoot + dir);
    if (entityStore == null) {
      Environment environment = getEnvironment(xodusRoot, dir);
      PersistentEntityStoreConfig config = new PersistentEntityStoreConfig();
      config.setManagementEnabled(false);
      config.setDebugSearchForIncomingLinksOnDelete(true);
      config.setRefactoringHeavyLinks(true);
      entityStore = PersistentEntityStores.newInstance(config, environment, "persistentEntityStore");
      PersistentEntityStore finalEntityStore = entityStore;
      entityStore.executeInTransaction(
              txn -> {
                finalEntityStore.registerCustomPropertyType(
                    txn, EmbeddedEntityIterable.class, EmbeddedEntityBinding.BINDING);
                finalEntityStore.registerCustomPropertyType(
                    txn, EmbeddedArrayIterable.class, EmbeddedEntityBinding.BINDING);
                persistentEntityStoreCache.put(xodusRoot + dir, finalEntityStore);
              });
    }
    PersistentEntityStore persistentEntityStore = persistentEntityStoreCache.get(xodusRoot + dir);
    return persistentEntityStore;
  }
```

And this property was originally saved with:

```
metaDataHashMap.put("uniqueProperties", uProperties);
finalEntity.setProperty(metadataProperty, new EmbeddedEntityIterable(metaDataHashMap));
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause of the problem.

Originally, the `EmbeddedEntityIterable` is under `com.mybusiness.model.EmbeddedEntityIterable` then was moved to `com.my-new-business.model.EmbeddedEntityIterable`

This solved the problem. However, it Xodus should have a facility to replace or at least replace references in cases like this the models are moved.

Comment: In my case the problem was caused because I was using custom types (using `PersistentEntityStore.registerCustomPropertyType()`) in some transactions, but not in others.